# spring boot starts by jetty instead of tomcat, what things to do?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jetty

now, the gradle is

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')
}
```

but the dependencies still exist tomcat 
[image]
[image]

Comment: No it doesn't include tomcat. It includes the tomcat connection pool... It does not contain the embedded Tomcat servlet container.

Comment: Which commands are you running? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: use IDEA gradle menu to get dependencies with no command

Answer (score 1):

Please correct quotes in the exclusion of Tomcat in your gradle as per the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-another-web-server):

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

Then clean and build the project.

Then confirm the Tomcat dependency is not present.